# An extra line is coming when drawing polygon in phonegap

Tags: cordova, google-maps-api-3

I am developing a project where i need to draw polygon on google map in phonegap. I used drawing manager tools for that as i require all the circle, rectangle etc. The problem arise when i use the tooltip for polygon more than 4-5 time continuously. For the first 2-3 time it is drawing the polygon in smooth way but after that it shows an extra line during the drawing as in image shown.

[image]

My code is :

```
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI3, 'touchstart', function() 
     {
         drawingManager.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON);
         drawingManager.setMap(map);
     });

     google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) 
     {
        if (event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) 
        {

          locatie = event.overlay.getPath().getArray();
          type="polygon";
          google.maps.event.addListener(event.overlay, 'bounds_changed', function() 
          {
                locatie =  event.overlay.getPath().getArray();
          });
          drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);           
        }
      });
```

Comment: `event.overlay` is a Polygon and it doesn't react to `bounds_changed` event.

Comment: its working fine with bounds change. problem with the tangent line coming

Comment: I don't use PhoneGap so maybe I'm wrong here: that line comes most probably from the last polygon point. If that is true than it's the same as desktop version: line follows mouse until you stop drawing and then disappears.

Comment: yes true. But is there any way to remove it

Comment: I don't know. I don't see any available option for that.